# UIPickerController memory leak after selecting photo

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, uiimagepickercontroller

I am having a memory leak whenever I select a photo within my image picker controller. I have tried doing my own research as to why this happens but I have found nothing close to my situation. Various tutorials I have learnt from have a memory leak when using the image picker controller as well. All I am doing is choosing a photo and then the image picker controller dismisses. I have tried finding a solution for many days now, but no luck, I tend to try to find solutions before asking for help, any help is greatly appreciated, here is my code.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];


[self.tableView reloadData];
if (self.image == nil && [self.videoFilePath length] == 0) {
    self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    self.imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 10;

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }
    else {
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }
    self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:self.imagePicker.sourceType];

    [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

}

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
    self.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];



   UIImage *newImage = [self resizeImage:self.image toWidth:200 andHeight:200];

    self.image = newImage;


    if (self.imagePicker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.image, nil, nil, nil);
    }
}
else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) {
    // A video was taken/selected!

    NSURL *videoUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    self.movieUrl = videoUrl;

    self.videoFilePath = videoUrl.absoluteString;

    if (self.imagePicker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
        // Save the video!

        if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(self.videoFilePath)) {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.videoFilePath, nil, nil, nil);
        }
    }
}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

When I use instruments I get, that the responsible instance is in Core Foundation. CFString. I am not very familiar with debugging memory leak's like these in Objective-C. I'd appreciate a hand here! Thank You.

Comment: How big is this leak?

Comment: @matt 304 Bytes

Comment: Now do a little math. How many times would a user have to do this operation, between launching and quitting your app, and leak 304 bytes each time, before reaching a significant amount, say, 1 MB?

Comment: @matt over 3k times. And I know it isn't much, but I was taught that memory leaks were a bad thing. Is it ever okay to just ignore them?

Comment: Have you any other choice? The leak is coming from Apple's code. The only thing you are doing wrong is retaining the UIImagePickerController. Stop doing that and move on. I'll give that advice as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The leak is coming from Apple's code. The only thing *you* are doing wrong is retaining the UIImagePickerController as an instance property. Stop doing that; create the UIImagePickerController as a temporary local variable each time you present it. Apart from that, there's nothing you can do.